# fs2 stream does not interrupt on Deferred

Tags: scala, cats-effect, fs2

The fs2 stream does not interrupt here:

```
import cats.effect.*
import fs2.Stream
import scala.concurrent.duration.*
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

val test = for {
      cancel <- Deferred[IO, Either[Throwable, Unit]]
      _ <- (IO.unit.delayBy(5.seconds).map { _ => println("Completing deferred"); cancel.complete(Right(())) }).start
      _ <- Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second).map(x => println(x)).interruptWhen(cancel).compile.drain
    } yield ()

test.unsafeRunSync()
```

but it interrupts if we swap the lines and fibers:

```
import cats.effect.*
import fs2.Stream
import scala.concurrent.duration.*
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

val test = for {
      cancel <- Deferred[IO, Either[Throwable, Unit]]
      _ <- Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second).map(x => println(x)).interruptWhen(cancel).compile.drain.start
      _ <- (IO.unit.delayBy(5.seconds).map { _ => println("Completing deferred"); cancel.complete(Right(())) })
    } yield ()

test.unsafeRunSync()
```

I wonder why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using `IO` properly.
Remember an `IO[A]` is just a program description, a value. It does nothing on its own.

When you call `cancel.complete` you are just creating a new program, it is not doing anything unless you compose it with other programs. And you are composing it in a `map` method; which doesn't really combine the programs, so your `cancel` is lost, and the `start` will just create a fiber that will create such a program and discard it.

In the second example, since `for` translates everything to a `flatMap` you ended up composing the program by accident.

The quick solution is to use `flatMap` rather than `map` in the first example.
But, IMHO, a better solution is using proper combinators like this:

```scala
val run: IO[Unit] =
  Deferred[IO, Either[Throwable, Unit]].flatMap { cancelToken =>
    val cancel =
      IO.sleep(5.seconds) >>
      IO.println("Completing deferred") >>
      cancelToken.complete(Right(()))

    val program =
      IO.println("Starting stream") >>
      Stream
        .awakeEvery[IO](1.second)
        .foreach(x => IO.println(x))
        .interruptWhen(cancelToken)
        .compile
        .drain >>
      IO.println("Stream finished")

  cancel.background.surround(program)
}
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/e0xuvhTSQ96HTQYLuMv0Qw/7)*.